# Tab buttons rise above virtual keyboard when textfield in activity has focus?

Tags: android, tabs

Focus of a textfield in any activity brings up the virtual keyboard. The view 
is then resized so that the tab buttons are displayed on top of the virtual 
keyboard ..

Hi have use this code but nothing happen tab is appearing above keyboard. in the applcation i hav e use activity group

Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain your question a bit more? I don't understand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

just add attribute of

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

in `Activity` tag from `AndoridManifest.xml`